# Trace route to distinguish whether connection type is local or remote

Tags: ios, networking, traceroute

In my project, I have two security methods for different route types.

If the app can connect to the server locally, we use the first method, which is connecting directly.

If the app must connect to the server through the internet, we use the second method which asks the user to input a PIN.

The app needs to be aware of the route to the server for security reasons. I need something like the Nice Trace app, in the background of my app.

Comment: Objective-C is just a programming language. What platform are you on?

Comment: @JoshCaswell iPhone iPad